# extract numbers from text In VB.net

Tags: vb.net, numbers

I need to extract numbers from text containing letters and numbers
Example

G 122.50 kg

G 171.50 kg

I use this code

```
Public Function GetNumber(ByVal text As String) As Double
    Dim rval As String = String.Empty
    Dim coll As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, "\d+")
    For Each a As Match In coll
        rval += a.ToString
    Next
    Return Convert.ToInt64(rval)
End Function
```

The result is 12250 or 17150 without adding the decimal point
The result will be wrong

Comment: Try  (\d+,)*\d+(\.\d*)?

Comment: @dbasnett   

System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Answer (score 1):

It does not add the decimal point because you are not telling it to add it. Use the pattern:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

It means

- `\d+` digits (at least one)
- `( )?` optional part
- `\.\d+` decimal separator + digits (at least one)

You can be also more specific. E.g., if the numbers always have 2 decimal digits, you can use `\d+\.\d\d`.

---

If the string are always structured like this, you could also split the string on the white space characters instead

```vb
Dim text As String = "G 171.50 kg"
Dim parts() As String = text.Split() ' = { "G", "171.50", "kg" }
Dim rval = parts(1)
```

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: I see that you are using `Convert.ToInt64`, but `Int64` = `long` is an integer number. Since you have a decimal part, use `Double.Parse` or `Convert.ToDouble` instead.